# Schengen visa documents if the job is just 2 month old

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, netherlands

I am applying for a Schengen short stay tourist visa at the Netherlands embassy this month. Since I am employed, the requirement for relevant documents for employed persons would be applicable. In addition to the NOC, the employment contract and my bank statements, I am also planning to support my application with pay slips but since I changed my job recently, I can only provide pay slips from last 2 months. I can provide pay slips from my previous job but there was a gap of a month between me leaving my older one and joining the new one. My question is:

1. How much would my application be affected if I do not submit pay slips?
2. If I do submit my pay slips, would a recent 1 month gap with no pay cast a negative effect on my application?
3. If so, any advice?

If it helps, I had a Schengen short stay tourist visa from Austria back in 2018. I have an Indian passport with Canadian Permanent Residency and will be applying in Toronto.

Comment: How many pay slips do they ask for?

Comment: I dont think they ask for payslips if https://www.netherlandsandyou.nl/binaries/netherlandsandyou/documents/publications/2017/01/01/checklist-schengenvisum---tourism-en/Checklist_Schengen_visa_tourism_EN.pdf is to be believed. But providing them would generally strengthen my application (I remember I had provided them the last time I got this visa). Other unofficial sources like https://visaguide.world/europe/netherlands-visa/requirements/ mention 3 months.

Comment: I think a one-month gap between jobs is nothing to be concerned about, but I cannot answer your first question about omitting the pay slips entirely.  I have no idea what effect this might have on your chances for success.